# Can't load module in while AngularJS unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for my angularJS 1.4.x app Services and Controllers, the problem is all our controllers and services are declared insides modules like shown below, i.e "MyApp"

```
module MyApp {

    'user strict';

     export class MyService {
          public static $inject = [
            '$http',
            '$rootScope',
            'library'
          ];
          constructor(private $rootScope:any,
                    private $http:ng.IHttpService,
                    private library:lib.Library) {}

          // some methods...
     }
}
```

but when i try to require this file in my test.js file it gives the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (1:7)
```

here is my test file

```
require('../../../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js');
require('../../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js');    
require('../ts/MyService.ts');

describe('myService testing', function(){

    beforeEach(
        angular.mock.module('app')
    );

    var ser;

    beforeEach(inject(function(myService) {
        ser = myService;
    }));

    it('1 + 1 should equal 2', function(){
        var actual = ser.addTwoNumbers(1,1);
        expect(actual).toEqual(2);
    });       
});
```

Comment: Try changing `require` to `import`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the Application is written in TypeScript, but the test is written in JavaScript.

When you run the test (as JavaScript) and require the parts that are written in TypeScript, they cannot be parsed by the JavaScript interpreter.

Compile your TypeScript to JavaScript and include the resulting files (*.js)  in your test, not the TypeScript source files (*.ts)